# location for notepad in android

Tags: java, android

I had created a notepad file automatically using `OutputStreamwriter`.

I just want to ask where is the location of the notepad file in my android project?
If ever there is a way to customize the location of that notepad file, may I know how?

```
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("playersdata.txt",MODE_APPEND));
```

Comment: Did you use internal or external storage?

Comment: Read this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: @EvanB, actually i just found the code in the internet and then i cant remember the link anymore what site was that so i don't have any idea if this is internal or external storage.

Comment: @user2699948 - Morrison's link will explain all.

Answer (score 1):

```
openFileOutput("playersdata.txt",MODE_APPEND)
```

Creates a FileOutputStream based on a File in the application's private folder of the **internal** storage.

To determine the actual path of that file, you can use the method to get a corresponding File object, and then get it's absolute path:

```
getFileStreamPath("playersdata.txt").getAbsolutePath()
```

Note that unless you alter the mode settings, you will not be able to interact with this file except from code that runs either as the application's package (by being part of it, or using the run-as shim on a debug APK, on a device where that isn't broken), or as root on an emulator/rooted device.  Another approach is to build functionality into your program to copy private files out to external storage so that you can examine them during the development stage.